# ECharts 3.0 custom map colors for USA States

Tags: javascript, echarts

How can I color each state in US Map with a custom color?

[This is the ECharts demo data I am using](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=map-usa&theme=light).

---

For example I want to color the states where Republican won with Red Color and Democrats in Blue color.

[According to the documentation](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#series-map.data.itemStyle.areaColor.color) setting up the color inside the data element array should do it. But is not working.

I would like [this map (colored)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udVIL.png) to look like [this map (duotone)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzYKG.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by setting the colors in the `visualMap` data.

---

I've played around a little, and you can do the following:

Set the `visualMap` to a range of 0 to 1, making it binary, and assign each value to either Democrat or Republican.

```
visualMap: {
    left: 'right',
    min: 0,
    max: 1,
    inRange: {
        color: ['#DE0100', '#031BBB']
    },
    text: ['Republican','Democrat'],
    calculable: true
},
```

Next, in `data`, set the value of each state to either `0` or `1`.

```
data:[
    {name: 'Alabama', value: 0},
    {name: 'Alaska', value: 0},
    {name: 'Arizona', value: 0},
    {name: 'Arkansas', value: 0},
    {name: 'California', value: 1},
    {name: 'Colorado', value: 1},
    {name: 'Connecticut', value: 1},
    {name: 'Delaware', value: 1},
    {name: 'District of Columbia', value: 0},
    {name: 'Florida', value: 0},
    {name: 'Georgia', value: 0},
    {name: 'Hawaii', value: 0},
    {name: 'Idaho', value: 0},
    {name: 'Illinois', value: 1},
    {name: 'Indiana', value: 0},
    {name: 'Iowa', value: 0},
    {name: 'Kansas', value: 0},
    {name: 'Kentucky', value: 0},
    {name: 'Louisiana', value: 0},
    {name: 'Maine', value: 1},
    {name: 'Maryland', value: 1},
    {name: 'Massachusetts', value: 1},
    {name: 'Michigan', value: 0},
    {name: 'Minnesota', value: 1},
    {name: 'Mississippi', value: 0},
    {name: 'Missouri', value: 0},
    {name: 'Montana', value: 0},
    {name: 'Nebraska', value: 0},
    {name: 'Nevada', value: 1},
    {name: 'New Hampshire', value: 1},
    {name: 'New Jersey', value: 1},
    {name: 'New Mexico', value: 1},
    {name: 'New York', value: 1},
    {name: 'North Carolina', value: 0},
    {name: 'North Dakota', value: 0},
    {name: 'Ohio', value: 0},
    {name: 'Oklahoma', value: 0},
    {name: 'Oregon', value: 1},
    {name: 'Pennsylvania', value: 0},
    {name: 'Rhode Island', value: 1},
    {name: 'South Carolina', value: 0},
    {name: 'South Dakota', value: 0},
    {name: 'Tennessee', value: 0},
    {name: 'Texas', value: 0},
    {name: 'Utah', value: 0},
    {name: 'Vermont', value: 1},
    {name: 'Virginia', value: 1},
    {name: 'Washington', value: 1},
    {name: 'West Virginia', value: 0},
    {name: 'Wisconsin', value: 0},
    {name: 'Wyoming', value: 0},
    {name: 'Puerto Rico', value: 0}
]
```

[image]

---

You can try it out by copy-pasting the data in the [map demo](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=map-usa)

Comment: Great suggestion. Even though we give up some metric for each state like electoral vote or win% etc, we can handle the same through mouse over. Thank you